# How to remove the dock icon on Mac Tauri?

Tags: macos, rust, tauri

I am trying to remove the dock icon, close the window, and let the app run in the background using Tauri.

I am able to close the window, but I don't know how to remove the app icon after the window is closed.

```rust
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]

#[tauri::command]
fn greet(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello ->, {}!", name)
}

fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            // #[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
            // app.set_activation_policy(tauri::ActivationPolicy::Accessory); // this removes the dock icon by default
            Ok(())
        })
        .build(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while building tauri application")
        .run(|_app_handle, event| match event {
// dock icon should be removed here, but I don't know how, share the app state?
            tauri::RunEvent::ExitRequested { api, .. } => {
                api.prevent_exit();
            }
            _ => {}
        })
}
```

Update:

I tried the provided answer

```
use cocoa::appkit::{NSApp, NSApplication, NSApplicationActivationPolicy::*};

unsafe {
    let app = NSApp();
    app.setActivationPolicy_(NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory);
}
```

It works, but this has the side effect of the app not being able to be opened from the spotlight search.

Comment: What is "the command bar"?

Comment: Ah sorry spotlight search @jnpdx

Comment: What happens when you try to launch it from Spotlight? It crashes?

Comment: Nothing is happening, the window is not opening, nothing seems to be crashing. I feel like this might be the issue, since the app is already running in the background. The window is not opening. I am trying to search for any APIs available in Tauri to capture when the app is opened from spotlight search. By doing that, I can create a new window.

I am simply trying to replicate how the fig.io window works; it is also written in Tauri

@jnpdx

Comment: Not sure what it is in the Tauri world, but in the AppKit world, I think the callback you're looking for is this one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428638-applicationshouldhandlereopen

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you for the lead; I found an open PR https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/pull/517

Answer (score 1):

Tauri doesn't seem to support setting the activation policy after startup, but you can set it yourself at runtime (see the comments and edits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317101/add-remove-application-icon-from-dock-at-runtime)) by calling the AppKit API using the `cocoa` crate:

```rust
use cocoa::appkit::{NSApp, NSApplication, NSApplicationActivationPolicy::*};

unsafe {
    let app = NSApp();
    app.setActivationPolicy_(NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory);
}
```

Inserting this immediately after the call to `api.prevent_exit()` causes the window to close and the dock icon to disappear, but the program continues running.

It's worth noting that Tauri doesn't expect you to do this, so it may cause other unexpected behavior -- it might be difficult to restore the window state later on, for example.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bring this up again, but when I use this approach, the app is not opening from the command bar.

Answer (score 1):

```
tauri::Builder::default().setup(|app| 
  app.set_activation_policy(tauri::ActivationPolicy::Accessory));
```

You may need Tauri v2 beta.2 or later.